# Power Query- Group by MAX

Tags: excel, grouping, powerquery

When using power query, get a max value from the table, but other column values are not shown. I want other column values.

I want Max Value in the Amount column, including other column values.I used Group By options also and got Max value not other column value.Any code available.

Answer (score 1):

Given the following sample data:

[image]

The trick is to create an all rows column and expand as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering my question...But in Max column three, 11 are shown.
Apples 11 03/01/2023 00:00:00 A.These values only I want from the table.

Comment: I don't understand. Please update your question with sample data and expected results.